# How to include multiple statements in the body of flatMap or flatMapMany for Mono or FLux in Spring Reactor?

Tags: spring, project-reactor

I have below code:

```
        Mono<Property> property = propertyService.findById(id);

        String title;

        Flux<Photo> photos = property.flatMapMany(prop -> 
        {
            title = prop.title + '-' + prop.type;

          return photoService.findByPropertyId(prop.getId());
        }
        );
        model.addAttribute("prop", property);
        model.addAttribute("title", title);
        model.addAttribute("photos", photos);
        // ajx is query param coming from request
        if(ajx != null && !ajx.isEmpty() && ajx.equals("1"))
            return Mono.just("fragments/propertyfrag");
        else
        return Mono.just("property");
```

The code shows what I want to achieve but it does not even compile. It gives error saying title and type on prop are not visible.

Note that the last statement is reference to thymeleaf template named property. Withn thyeleaf template I have access to variable prop as if it was not reactive but plain prop object that enables me to directly access parameters on prop object. Does that mean within thymeleaf template property.block() has been performed?

In actual code there is some business logic that I need to do after getting title variable in above code and therefore I cannot avail the use of prop passed as model attribute to thymleaf template  to directly get title within thymeleaf.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind your `Flux<Photo>` is an asynchronous process, so it cannot update the `title` variable outside of it in this imperative style. Note that your `Flux<Photo>` is also never subscribed to or composed upon, so it will effectively never be invoked...

To answer your other question, yes in Spring Framework 5 having a `Mono` in the `Map` passed to Thymeleaf will resolve that Mono lazily and inject the resulting value in the Thymeleaf model.

Pending more information on the use of `photos` flux, for the title generation you probably need to compose more:

```
propertyService.findById(id)
    .doOnNext(prop -> model.addAttribute("prop", prop)) //reactively add the prop to the model
    .flatMapMany(prop -> {
        String title = prop.title + '-' + prop.type;
        if(validate(title)) //do some validation
            return photoService.findByPropertyId(prop.getId());
        else
            return Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("validation failed"));
    }) //not sure what you do with the `Photo`s there :/
    //for now let's ignore the flux photos and at the end simply emit a String to change the view:
    .thenReturn("property"); //then(Mono.just("property")) in older versions of reactor 3.1.x
```

Comment: Thank you Simon. I updated my question to show clearly what I want. In particular I added model.addAttribute("title", title);
        model.addAttribute("photos", photos);  to make it more clear. In view of this its not clear how can I use your solution.

Comment: Do I need to add validate method somewhere in the controller code?